# Triangular numbers boolean function

Tags: number-theory

I read the new book by Paul Wellin *Programming in Mathematica*.
There is an exercise about triangular numbers.
(The `n-`th triangular number is defined as the sum of the integers `1` through `n`.
They are so named because they can be represented visually by arranging rows of dots in a triangular manner. The first ten triangular numbers are: `1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45`.)

In the solution there are given functions which will give the nth triangular number.

For instance:

```
f1[n_] := Total[Range[n]]

f2[n_] := Fold[#1 + #2 &, 0, Range[n]]

f3[n_] := Binomial[n + 1, 2]
```

Regarding the timings, we have `f3 > f1 > f2` (using the number 50000005000000 from Wellin's book) (in my laptop t3 = 0.01 sec, t1 = 0.18 sec, t3 = 3.8 sec).

I was thinking about a boolean function that will return true or false, whether the number is triangular or not.

My procedural style approach is:

```
triangularQ[n_] :=
 Module[{y, dy}, For[y = 0; dy = 1, y < n, y += dy++];
  If[y == n, Print[True], Print[False]]]
```

But it does not look so efficient.

Are there other approaches that use functional programming?

It seems good to compare the various solutions (the number `50000005000000` is from Wellin's book).

First the procedural:

```
In[182]:= triangularQ[50000005000000] // Timing

During evaluation of In[182]:= True

Out[182]= {41.562500, Null}
```

Aky's

```
In[185]:= f[x_, n_] := f[x - n, n + 1]; f[0, n_] := True;
f[x_ /; x < 0, n_] := False

In[193]:=
Block[{$IterationLimit = ∞}, f[50000005000000, 1]] // Timing

Out[193]= {114.703125, True}
```

Eldo's

I coud not get true for

```
MemberQ[ f2 /@ Range@(10^7), 50000005000000]
```

in reasonable time (less than $2$ minutes).

Nasser's

```
In[226]:= triangularQ[50000005000000] // Timing

During evaluation of In[226]:= True

Out[226]= {41.421875, Null}
```

So the procedural style is not deficient at all :-)!

Comment: Here's a functional approach: define `f[x_, n_] := f[x - n, n + 1]; f[0, n_] := True; f[x_ /; x < 0, n_] := False` and evaluate `f[testNumber, 1]`, if `True` it is a triangular number, if `False` then not. Of course, there's an explicit formula for triangular numbers (try `Sum[k, {k, 1, n}]`) so using that formula you could simply check whether the number being tested has a positive integral solution in `n`. But that's no longer a functional programming solution.

Comment: Aky I know that formula Sum[k, {k, 1, n}] will return the nth triangular number but I cannot understand what do you mean by "...you could simply check whether the number being tested has a positive integral solution in n..."

Comment: If m is a triangular number then m == n(n+1)/2 will be satisfied by some positive integer n, otherwise it won't.

Comment: I obtain much quicker times (<1ms) than you cite for @Nasser `Binomial` approach  - you may want to `Clear` formulae and variables and retest?

Comment: You are right! My apologies to Nasser!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another approach (based on $t_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$):

```
fn[x_] := Mod[Sqrt[1 + 8 x], 2] == 1
```

For the test example `fn[3003]` is true:

Just for fun (but factoring extremely large numbers an issue):

```
an[x_?(# > 0 &)] := 
 Abs[# - 2 x/#] & @@ Nearest[Divisors[ 2 x], Sqrt[2 x]] == 1
an[0] := True
```

Just for illustration (and not proof but are straightforward to show): this is picking from 0,1,...,100 the triangular numbers.

```
fnf = Pick[Range[0, 100], fn[#] & /@ Range[0, 100]]
anf = Pick[Range[0, 100], an[#] & /@ Range[0, 100]]
tn = Table[j (j + 1)/2, {j, 0, Length[anf] - 1}]
Grid[Prepend[
  Transpose[
{tn, fnf, anf}], {"Triangular number", "fn", "an"}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Testing the case in edited question (and using Mr Wizard `timeAvg` function):

```
timeAvg[func_] := 
 Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 
   15}]
{timeAvg[#], #} &@fn[50000005000000]
```

yields:{1.47200*10^-8, True}

Comment: What is this timeAvg function?

Comment: Definetely, very quick!

Comment: @dimitris Mr. Wizard provided this code as a way to get the average timing of a function/procedure by doing it over and over again. You can search the site for more insights.

Comment: @ubqdqn +1 how would you code (f.e. with a `Manipulate`) images like here: [link](http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F1%2F1c%2FFirst_six_triangular_numbers.svg%2F374px-First_six_triangular_numbers.svg.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTriangular_number&h=314&w=374&tbnid=k0ZhBbVi8fi32M%3A&zoom=1&docid=oVRKs3Q3qVs3iM&ei=QcDBU4OGCMiUO6C9gPgN&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=1554&page=1&start=0&ndsp=36&ved=0CCkQrQMwAA)? I tried but ended up with extremely ugly code.

Comment: @eldo sorry for the delay in replying...this is related and in the post there is a link to a notebook...I have not looked at this since the time...my code may be ugly: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39347/1997

Answer (score 7):

There is an especially useful function `HarmonicNumber` appearing most likely **the best approach** in similar tasks since its implementation is optimized and it has close relations to number theoretic functions like the Riemann zeta function `ζ` represented in *Mathematica* by `Zeta`, basically `HarmonicNumber` tends to `Zeta` for `Re[z] > 1` :

```
Limit[ HarmonicNumber[n, z], n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> Re[z] > 1]
```

> ```
> Zeta[z]
> ```

where `z` can be an arbitrary complex number with the real part greater than $1$.

We ask if a given integer `k` is triangular, i.e. if there exist another integer `n` such that $$1 + 2 + \ldots + n = k$$
Here is a straightforward implementation of  natural (direct) approach:

```
tri[k_Integer] := Resolve @ Exists[ n, n ∈ Integers && n > 0, 
                                    k == HarmonicNumber[n, -1]]
```

It works this way:

```
tri /@ Range[3, 10]
```

> ```
> {True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True}
> ```

It can be **generalized to a more universal solution**, namely when we are looking for higher order triangular numbers, e.g. `HarmonicNumber[n, -p]` yields the following sum
$$1^p + 2^p + \ldots + n^p = k(n,p)$$

```
tri[k_Integer, p_Integer] := Resolve @ Exists[ n, n ∈ Integers && n > 0, 
                                                 k == HarmonicNumber[n, -p]]
```

e.g. this gives a few first order triangular numbers

```
{#, HarmonicNumber [n, -#]} & /@ Range[5] // TableForm // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

and of course

```
HarmonicNumber[n, -p] == Sum[k^p, {k, n}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

To conclude we underline that the solution based on `HarmonicNuber` is the fastest, the most general and sheds light on crucial number theoretic objects.

Comment: always learning something...thank you for nice answer

Answer (score 6):

The $n^{th}$ triangle number satisfies `Binomial[n+1,2]`, therefore, solving for `m=Binomial[n+1,2]` and checking if the solution is an integer gives the answer directly.

```
triangularQ[m_] := IntegerQ@(n /. First@Solve[Binomial[n + 1, 2] == m, n])

{#, triangularQ[#]} & /@ Range[2, 28] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 4):

Well, not to beat a dead horse, but there is a way to do this using simple arithmetic, the pieces of which are in some of the responses given so far. Since any triangular number T is equal to n(n+1)/2 for some n, a bit of algebraic manipulation gives:

```
2T = n^2 + n
8T = 4n^2 + 4n
```

Completing the square:

```
8T + 1 = 4n^2 + 4n + 1
       = (2n+1)^2
```

So, T is triangular if 8T+1 is an odd perfect-square. Here then is the test:

```
SquareNumberQ[n_]:= IntegerQ[Sqrt[n]];
TriangularNumberQ[t_]:= OddQ[Sqrt[8t+1]] && SquareNumberQ[8t+1]

TriangularNumberQ[50000005000000]//Timing
{0.000045, True}
```

Finding all triangular numbers less than 10^6 takes about 8 seconds on my computer using

```
Select[Range[10^6], TriangularNumberQ]
```

Comment: I just saw the reply from Mr. Wellin. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

```
MemberQ[f2 /@ Range@1000, 3003]
```

> True

```
With[{r = Range@10, tri = f2 /@ Range@1000}, Transpose[{r, MemberQ[tri, #] & /@ r}]] // TableForm
```

[image]

```
Take[CoefficientList[Series[x/(1 - x)^3, {x, 0, 100}], x], -10]
```

> {4186, 4278, 4371, 4465, 4560, 4656, 4753, 4851, 4950, 5050}

Answer (score 2):

This is not a computationally efficient solution, but it works also in a spreadsheet:

```
nn = 12;
a = Table[Sum[If[n == k*(k + 1)/2, 1, 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
b = Table[If[a[[i]] == 1, True, False], {i, 1, nn}]
```

Output:

{True, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False}