# Visualising the Twelve Days of Christmas in 3D

Tags: graphics3d, code-request, svg-format

On a related topics, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39338/how-many-christmas-gifts). ***I am wondering if it is possible to make a better visualisation of this [svg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_visualisation.svg) file in Mathematica, so I can see it in 3D and rotate it too.***

Note if you pause your mouse onto any "day", this is actually an animation.

The number of (total) gifts of this problem is really easy and we can just use something like

```
Accumulate[Accumulate[Table[i, {i, 12}]]]
```

Comment: The total is has a closed form solution and is given by `(1/6)*n*(1 + n)*(2 + n) /. n -> 12`

Comment: @m_goldberg yes I know. It's also very easy to derive.

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: @m_goldberg To make a 3D version of the SVG file in Mathematica if possible.

Comment: @george2079  To make a 3D version of the SVG file in Mathematica if possible.

Comment: sorry it sounds like you have no ideas or code problems and are just asking folks to develop "something better" ??

Comment: @george2079 Yes. I have no experience to creating 3D "objects" in MMA. I just wonder if we can creat something similar so that I can actually rotate to see this tetrahedal.

Comment: yes you can, check Texture, Translate, NestList documentation for hint

Answer (score 2):

This can be a starting point:

```
vtc = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
coords = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
     0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 
     1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 
     1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 
     1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}};
box = Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Table[vtc, {6}]];

boxes = {Texture[ImageResize[ExampleData[#], 50]], box} & /@ 
   RandomSample[ExampleData["ColorTexture"], 12];

mgift = Table[
   NestList[Translate[#, {-1, 0, 0}] &, 
    Translate[boxes[[i]], {0, 0, i - 1}], i - 1], {i, 1, 12}];

agift = Table[
   Rest@NestList[Translate[#, {0, 1.3, 0}] &, 
     Translate[mgift[[i]], {0, 1.3 (i - 1), 0}], 13 - i], {i, 1, 12}];

Graphics3D[agift, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```