# Automatically grouping words into categories

Tags: list-manipulation, wolfram-alpha-queries

Say I have a comma-separated list of words. For example sake, let it be things I have seen during my trip to a safari zone. It would look something like that:

```
zebra, lion, car, ranger, teacup, honey badger, lake,
```

and so on. I would like Mathematica to automatically separate it in different categories such as:

```
"animals", "objects", "humans", "scenery"
```

Is there a way to do this in Mathematica 10, possibly using the WolframAlpha functionalities?

Comment: Do you know how to define lists ? How to manipulate them (basic operations) ? Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Fair comment. I do know how to manipulate lists, but I am not quite sure about the machine learning capabilities of Mathematica, and all of the stuff using the curated database.

Comment: `SemanticInterpretation[#, AmbiguityFunction -> All] & /@ {"zebra", 
  "lion", "car", "ranger", "teacup", "honey badger", "lake"}` the results aren't very promising.

Comment: You should look at `Classify` (the built-in classifier `Classify["FacebookTopic", list]` has too few categories unfortunately). You may also find `WordData[word, "BroaderTerms"]` useful.

Comment: @Pickett yes, very unpromising. One of the interpretations for "car" is a specie of the animal kingdom!

Comment: So far, Classify is the one that seems to work best. However still not satisfying. Does anyone know a good source of documentation for these "Wolfram Research" functionalities?

Comment: possibly related and useful  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66987/how-to-perform-document-classification-i-e-extracting-topics-from-text

Comment: Another option - use Rlink and the [RTextTools](http://www.rtexttools.com/) package.

Answer (score 5):

## Note

This answer was meant for a bit of fun but instead does a good job of managing expectations for `Entity` in the WL at present.

## Image Identify and Google Image Search

Wolfram have heavily promoted their `ImageIdentify` project (http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/05/13/wolfram-language-artificial-intelligence-the-image-identification-project/) which might be a good way to categorise your terms. But we need images first.

@Szabolcs provides a method for obtaining Google Image Search results in their answer here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20485/1952

```
googImageSearch[term_] := 
 With[{json = Import["https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=" <> StringReplace[term, " " -> "%20"], "JSON"]}, 
  Import["url" /. ("results" /. ("responseData" /. json))[[1]]]]
```

Unfortunately, this API is deprecated and occasionally returns html instead of an image, which was terrifying when returned in the middle of a list of images:

```
StringTake[googImageSearch["lion"], 45]
(*"All you need to know about your night dreams."*)
```

In lieu of a better option (I don't want a Custom Google Search which is limited to 100 hits a day), I'll restrict `googImageSearch` to a specific domain (wikipedia):

```
googImageSearch[term_, site_] := 
 With[{json = 
    Import["https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=\
1.0&q=site:" <> site <> "+" <> StringReplace[term, " " -> "%20"], 
     "JSON"]}, 
  Import["url" /. ("results" /. ("responseData" /. json))[[1]]]];
words = {"zebra", "lion", "car", "park ranger", "teacup", 
   "badger honey", "lake"};
wikiImages = Map[googImageSearch[#, "en.wikipedia.org"] &, words];
```

These images are now ready for classification by `ImageIdentify`, I convert the `Entity` returned to its `FullForm` representation:

```
identifyImages = ImageIdentify /@ wikiImages;
Multicolumn[
 MapThread[
  Labeled[#1, #2, Top] &, {wikiImages, 
   FullForm /@ identifyImages}], 4, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

These `Entity["Concept",_]` have a number of `"Properties"` that might be useful to us:

```
FullForm /@ identifyImages[[1]]["Properties"]
{EntityProperty["Concept","AlternateNames"],EntityProperty["Concept","BroaderConcepts"],EntityProperty["Concept","Definition"],EntityProperty["Concept","EquivalentEntity"],EntityProperty["Concept","Name"],EntityProperty["Concept","NarrowerConcepts"],EntityProperty["Concept","SimilarEntities"],EntityProperty["Concept","SubsetConcepts"],EntityProperty["Concept","SupersetConcepts"],EntityProperty["Concept","WordDataSenses"],EntityProperty["Concept","WordNetID"]}
```

The `Entity["Concept","EquivalentEntity"]` property is the most promising, but alas provides less use than @Picket's suggested use of `SemanticInterpretation`:

```
Multicolumn[
 MapThread[
  Labeled[#1, #2, Top] &, {wikiImages, 
   FullForm /@ 
    Map[#[EntityProperty["Concept", "EquivalentEntity"]] &, 
     identifyImages]}], 4, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

## SemanticInterpretation

@Pickett mentioned in the comments that `SemanticInterpretation` provides disappointing results, which it does but they can (sometimes) be improved by restricting the `Entity` classes within which you look.

`EntityValue` provides all `Entity` classes available, excluding `"Word"` is a logical choice and can be done as follows:

```
allEntities = EntityValue[]; 
allEntities$nowords = DeleteCases[allEntities, "Word"];
semanticInterp = (SemanticInterpretation[#1,Alternatives @@ (Entity[#1, __] & ) /@ allEntities$nowords] &) /@ words; 
semanticInterp = FullForm /@ semanticInterp
```

[image]

We can now group these words by the class of `Entity` returned using `GroupBy`:

```
GroupBy[Transpose[{words, semanticInterp /. Entity[a_, _] :> a}], Last]
(*<|Species->{{zebra,Species},{lion,Species},{car,Species},{honey badger,Species}},
City->{{ranger,City}},$Failed->{{teacup,$Failed}},Surname->{{lake,Surname}}|>*)
```