# Downloading a number of images from a web site as a list

Tags: import, data-acquisition, internet

For a MachineLearning project I need to form a training set using images taken from the web page containing lots of them. Like, for example [this one](https://www.google.de/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1543&bih=922&q=roadman&oq=roadman&gs_l=img.1.0.0l10.5223.5653.2.10170.3.3.0.0.0.0.62.182.3.3.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.7.483.QK6G3Kpn_eY#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=across%20the%20road). It would be very convenient, if all the images from this site could be downloaded and transformed into a list of images, such that I could later simply delete those I do not like. Then it is easy to transform it into a training set.

Any ideas of how to download/form a list of images?

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20484)?

Comment: @ J. M. Thank you for the reference, but you did not understand my question. It is not "how to import a page". It is about "how to transform multiple images containing in the page into a list of images"

Comment: Well, you linked to Google Image Search as an example; I merely pointed out that related thread that involves extracting the images returned by Google Image Search.

Comment: Import seems to work for me - Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica", "Images"] is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote this in the comment, but the code did not come out properly formatted. So here it is again:

```
Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica", "Images"]
```

[image: Import Images as a list]

Comment: This works to an extent with a Google image search, like in OP's query.  `Import["http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=baby+elephant",
"Images"]` returns a list of the first 20 images, in thumbnail size.

Comment: @Lotus Thank you, it works, though not as I expect. Namely, it, indeed, imports the images, but only a small part of them. Have you ideas of how to import them all?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch The 20 images you get are the ones from **page 1**.

Comment: @ Karsten 7 How can I get the images from other pages then? You see, to train the machine I need lots of images. Impossible to pick them up by hand.

Comment: I'd presume google detects the request is not from a browser and serves up a limited number. I realize its not elegant, but you can go to google images in a browser and `save page as` to get all the images (~400) dumped to a folder, then import the files.  Of course they are thumbnails. You'd need to navigate each link to get the full size images.